# Transaction security policy for multiple logins

Tags: transaction, shield

I need to modify the existing transaction security policy to trigger if user logs in from multiple IP addresses in past 8 hours. I'm using the below SFDC example policy. Can someone give a hand on how to tweak the below code to trigger for 8 hours. Currently the policy is configured to trigger for past 24 hours.

```
global class LoginPolicyCondition implements TxnSecurity.PolicyCondition {
 public boolean evaluate(TxnSecurity.Event e) {
   AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT SourceIp
                                FROM LoginHistory
                                WHERE UserId = :e.userId
                                      AND LoginTime = LAST_N_DAYS:1
                                GROUP BY SourceIp];
   if(!results.isEmpty() && results.size() > 1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is mostly identical to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238553/soql-to-get-list-of-ip-addresses-for-past-8-hours) but with more context. Please edit your questions to expand on them rather than creating duplication.

Comment: David - I deleted the identical question since it was duplicate as you pointed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no SOQL [Date Literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) equivalent to to `LAST_N_DAYS:1` that will give you a period of 8 hours.

Instead, you can just calculate the date range and use that in the SOQL query instead.

```
DateTime eightHoursAgo = DateTime.now().addHours(-8);
AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT SourceIp
                            FROM LoginHistory
                            WHERE UserId = :e.userId
                                  AND LoginTime >= :eightHoursAgo
                            GROUP BY SourceIp];
return (!results.isEmpty() && results.size() > 1);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Appreciate your help on this.